# Nesting Microdata vs. independent Items

Tags: seo, microdata

I've been reading about Microdata and its implementation, however the examples are quite simple and I'm yet to find a website that thoroughly implements structured data throughout the entire site.

So as I was implementing the markup I started to dig up questions on how would be the best way to do this. One of the main dilemmas I'm facing is whether it's best to create independent items (Schema.org items) or rather create an item that represents the page with all its content as nested items that belong to that parent item.

So I could have markup that would reflect the following:

```
- Company
- Product
- Offers
- Article
```

Or it could be something like this:

```
- Company
    - Product
        - Article
    - Offers
```

Where the indentation reflects its nesting (for this question I didn't bother to figure out if this is actually doable for these item types, it's just a generic pseudo-example).

So basically I'm just not sure how a search engine would use this information, because if I nest it, the page would contain a single item with various properties (that would be items themselves) but I'm unaware as to how these examples would be treated and which would be the pros and cons of each solution.

Comment: If anyone wants to help out on another related question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489028/microdata-reuse-within-another-item

Comment: When you refer to "nesting", do you mean the HTML level (child elements) or the Microdata level (properties with item value)?

Comment: @unor I'm refering to microdata level nesting of items within their appropriate properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated: I suggest nesting types/elements when mark-up appears to require it. The reason is simple. You never know how the data will be used and where nesting is appropriate, nesting will give a clearer picture of the data you are marking-up.

Nesting does not always seem possible when you try and stitch mark-up into your HTML. It can be a real struggle sometimes. This is an important challenge to conquer. In this case, you may need to use `id` and then `itemref` to refer to parts of your schema definition to create relationships. The more data that you try and mark-up, the more difficult it will become to juggle all of the types/elements and therefore some compromises may need to be made- but never compromise on nesting types and elements and never break them up. The reason is simple. Nesting allows types and elements to have relationships. Breaking up types/elements and not properly nesting them will break the relationships between types/elements and make the mark-up less effective.]

I also strongly warn anyone to pay attention to nesting. Your mark-up may appear correct but not work while a simple nesting issue exists. I have seen this several times on this site. It can be confusing using mark-up and anyone can go cross-eyed very quickly.

Comment: I can't vote up for now, but thanks... I'll wait a couple of days to see if we get more input, but I had a gut feeling that would be the case. I just wasn't sure if it would be safe to assume they (search engines) would extract the information as a single item or as individual items with relationships when nested

Comment: Thanks! Schema.org mark-up is actually still new and in 2013/2014, Google was still writing code to handle the definitions that schema.org had. I suspect that Google is still hot on this and I am (almost) willing to bet the farm (since I have one) that Google will push mark-up even further. From a big-data perspective, this is a huge *new* advantage in the search world and I am sure that Google realizes it too.

Comment: I'm counting on it also, I'm relatively new to webdesign so I'm trying to get into something fresh in the marketplace to try and have some worth over other types of practices. We gotta put our money on a horse to try and win :p

Comment: Btw I commented on my question regarding a related question I made. I'd love to hear your opinion on it, since it's implementation goes towards the cross-eye you mentioned

Comment: I suspect that anyone who uses mark-up in an advanced way including extensions will be rewarded suddenly and in a big way by Google. Bing seems to be doing a really good job too. I just get the feeling that Google is way ahead of Bing while holding their cards close to the vest.

Comment: I think there's regulation in place in the US so that Google's and other search engine's modifications don't affect the market too much after an update (it's just hearsay for me, I didn't read it anywhere official, although it makes sense). I heard there was a sort of a crisis there when they changed the algorithm a couple of years back, but again I've got no proof on that, just hearsay. Although I have a feeling this schema business is going to catch on, the rewards will have to be gradual to avoid exploits

Comment: It may be somewhat gradual as you said, but those early adopters will see sudden results being ahead of the game. They will benefit from the Early Adopter Curve found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_innovations Early adopters always win the competition war! That is what Google did with the PageRank algorithm and no-one has been able to catch up yet.

Comment: Given what I figured out in my other question, I think it would be important to mention that nesting microdata items is important since it creates relationships between bits of data, but it's important not to attempt to try and match HTML nesting with microdata nesting.

Comment: @Fernando Silva Thanks for sharing that! This is how we all learn.

Comment: No problem, I'm just glad I figured things out and was able to help at the same time. Just tweak your answer regarding the nesting separation so I can accept it. I don't think there'll be much controversy on what was said

Comment: @Fernando Silva I hope I got it right this time! I tried to be clear that mark-up, where it applies, should always be nested and not broken up.

Comment: The only thing I would change is the part about having to reformat/reorganize your content and make compromises about what to tag. Keep in mind that with the `itemref` and `id` attributes you can simply pick any part of your html and place it within any microdata item anywhere on the page, regardless of your html nesting, take a look here -> http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/65570/12463

Comment: @Fernando Silva Got it. Thanks! I made a minor change. I will sometime in the future try and write a web page(s) on this topic where I will detail the options. This will strengthen my skill-sets of course, but also give me a reference that I can use to refer to. One thing I like about W.SE is that it gives me ideas of what webmasters need that I can provide on a website somewhere. My problem is that I am so busy these days that it can take me some time to get to these things.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/65570/12463 - I added a link to that answer to where I got it, lots of cool tricks in there and don't forget to use the microdata testing tool here - https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets