# Microdata reuse within another item

Tags: seo, html5, microdata

My intention is marking up my site with Microdata in a way I won't need to re-declare items that already exist in the page.

For example, my header will always contain info regarding the "Organization" that the website represents. Within the "Products" that I offer I can specify the "Brand" of that product. So the product's property "brand" will replicate the "Organization" info mentioned in the header.

Now I don't think I'm supposed to repeat the organization's markup within the brand property of the product item, since I feel there should be a way to reference that organization item directly.

I just haven't found a way to do this, are there any ideas? I've checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8364191/1067465) and although useful it doesn't address my issue.

I tried messing with it however to give you an idea of my intentions:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="myCompany">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Company Name" />
    <meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com/" />
    <meta itemprop="description" content="description" />
</span>

<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <span itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="id" content="myCompany" id="myCompany" />
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Foo product" />
    <meta itemprop="description" content="You can do Bar with it" />
</span>
```

This doesn't work since it adds the the "id" property to both "Organization" and "Product".

#### EDIT1:

zigojacko's answer didn't really go towards what I was expecting, since he uses a single container with all the information needed to present all the markup for his product.

However in my case the site layout isn't broken down into a container that would hold all the necessary information, as my company info is within the header and the products/offers are near the footer (as the main form to define those offers is above the fold) and other info is scattered between each of those containers.

As such I would eventually like to link the company (that resides in the header) to the brand of each product (that reside near the footer), I just wouldn't like to repeat all the code necessary to describe the company and therefor would prefer linking to some sort of item identifier.

There is also the possibility of nesting every bit of content within the page to the company, but as a comment to this question I mention that specific question in the Webmasters Stack Exchange. So I know how to pull that type of solution off, I'm just wondering if there's the possibility of referring to an existent item elsewhere on the page.

#### EDIT2:

In the comments of this question I might have found a better way to explain what I mean.

> By pointers I mean an html attribute that could reference an Item. In
>   the code example I gave, I have a loose (not nested) Organization that
>   I would like to be inserted into my second item Product within it's
>   brand property, but without having to copy+paste or echo again within
>   the Product. I tried to simulate that behavior with the itemref
>   attribute.

Comment: I have seen mark-up extend through-out the entire page with nested elements beginning in the header and ending in the footer. This works! It adds confusion when coding your page/pages especially with automation involved. I also will note that it is okay to re-use a type with an open/close and specify different data elements in each. This works too! Though it would probably be best to nest through-out the entire page if possible. Because mark-up is new(ish), not all cases are thoroughly known, but so far Google seems to be handling these two cases rather well that I can see (so far).

Comment: @Yes, I have a diagram ready to go for that case, where I implement the markup throughout the entire `body` tag, within an "Organization" or "Product" item type.

I am thinking however that I could declare the "Organization" within the header, but then use it with a pointer later within the code to create the relationship. This would allow me to have less to worry about in regards to containers and what properties are getting linked to what items.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by pointers unless it is within the code that creates the page. It would be nice if schema.org was more relational in nature. Perhaps it is and I do not know it yet. I have seen data elements used anywhere as long as the type is not closed. BTW- I do not like the term *type* used by schema.org. I wish they would use database terms like the rest of us. Even the term subject may be clearer.

Comment: By pointers I mean an html attribute that could reference an `Item`. In the code example I gave, I have a loose (not nested) `Organization` that I would like to be inserted into my second item `Product` within it's `brand` property, but without having to copy+paste or echo again within the `Product`. I tried to simulate that behavior with the `itemref` attribute.

Comment: Oh I see. Clever!! I am not sure if this works. I have not seen anyone do this before. Perhaps it will. Who knows? If you can afford to, you can experiment with this and see what comes of it. If you cannot afford it, then nesting through-out the page may be the best answer. But if nesting becomes too difficult, it is okay to open a type again if necessary- that I have seen so far. If you want to experiment, then perhaps a smaller portion of your mark-up where you can track the results. This is all *new* and so I am sure experiments will open up a whole new world that no-one saw coming.

Comment: Yeah, I was just testing and saw that even **within** an item `<div itemscope itemtype="something"><span itemscope itemtype="somethingElse"></span></div>` I can redeclare this same structure for some other item and as long as it doesn't contain an `itemprop` attribute in its outermost tag, it jumps out of the nesting. This means `somethingElse` won't be a child of `something`, which is helpfull, although not what I'm looking for

Comment: You have already gotten ahead of me! I am a simple coder mostly because I am simple... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after poking google hard for several hours, it finally coughed up what I needed, right [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html)

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="a1 b"></div>
<p id="a1">Name: <span itemprop="name">Amanda</span></p>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="a2 b"></div>
<p id="a2">Name: <span itemprop="name">Fernando</span></p>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="a3 b"></div>
<p id="a3">Name: <span itemprop="name">Daniel</span></p>

<div id="b" itemprop="nationality" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Country" itemref="c"></div>
<div id="c"><p>Nationality: <span itemprop="name">uk</span></p></div>
```

So the result is:

```
Person
    name: Amanda
    nationality [Country]:
        name: uk
Person
    name: Fernando
    nationality [Country]:
        name: uk
Person
    name: Daniel
    nationality [Country]:
        name: uk
```

And I only declared "nationality" once in this block of code. So basically it's separating the nesting of HTML from the nesting of microdata items, or at least not making the mistake of assuming they should coincide, since in most cases we don't think our data or layout according to schema.org's items.

Hope this helps someone who's banging their head as hard as I did.

Answer (score 2):

The Schema markup for a product should be like:-

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/product">
            <div itemprop="name"><strong>Product Name</strong></div>
    </a>
    <div itemprop="description">This is my product description.</div>
    <div itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <span itemprop="name">My Brand</span></div>
    <div itemprop="manufacturer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
Manufactured by: <span itemprop="name">The Manufacturer</span></div>
    <div>Model: <span itemprop="model">V1.0</span></div>
    <div>Product ID: <span itemprop="productID">abc</span></div>
    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">149</span> reviews
        </div>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><span itemprop="price">£9.99</span><link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition" /> New
        </div>
    </div>
```

It is perfectly okay to include the itemtype 'Organization' for the brand within a product schema if there is an organisation declared in the header of your page.

You could in fact have 10 products on a page all with different brands providing it is marked up within the Product itemtype.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question with a bit more info. You answer is correct, but that wasn't really what I was looking for.

Comment: Updated, let me know if what I wrote isn't understandable. Thanks